# What is the base date for Facebook feed created_time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am handling facebook page feed with webhooks. As part of response I got following JSON. Here I observe `time=1451367053` value is not no. of milliseconds from **1 Jan 1970**. What is the base Date they use to calculate No. of milliseconds

```
{entry=[{id=407976012733132, time=1451367053, changes=[{field=feed, value={item=post, verb=add, post_id=407976012733132_420062131524520, is_hidden=false, sender_id=1540815732897198, message=<>, sender_name=Havasay Hs}}]}], object=page}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the number of seconds since Jan, 1st 1970 ("epoch time"):

```
 $ perl -e 'print scalar localtime 1451367053'
 Tue Dec 29 13:30:53 2015
```

If you want the number of milliseconds since that day, just multiply by 1000.